# How to pass this tar command as argument to python subprocess

Tags: python

If I am running the command that is specified in the args on the terminal then it goes successfully on terminal but doing the same in python program is not working; I am seeing junk characters in the screen to the size of the input tar file and lot of xterm words too;

I feel the problem is handling the ' ' letters in the args;

```
 import subprocess

 try:
     args = "cat parsing.tgz <(echo -n ''| gzip)> new-file.tgz".split()
     subprocess.check_call(args)
 except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
     print e
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @Chris; I updated my question specific to your comments.

Comment: Off topic, but instead of using `split()` you should use [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shlex.html#shlex.split).

Comment: @squiguy I looks like shlex fails to parse the special character ' '  :( and I am getting error ; The arg after shlex.split() is ['cat', 'parsing.tgz', '<(echo', '-n', '|', 'gzip)>', 'new-file.tgz'];

Answer (score 1):

I am not specialist, but this i found - this commands not working in `sh`, but working in `bash`:

```
$ sh -c "cat parsing.tgz <(echo -n ''| gzip)> new-file.tgz"
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `cat parsing.tgz <(echo -n ''| gzip)> new-file.tgz'
$
$ bash -c "cat parsing.tgz <(echo -n ''| gzip)> new-file.tgz"
$
```

Thats a reason why it not work in subprocess directly. This code looks work fine:

```
import subprocess
command = "cat parsing.tgz <(echo -n ''| gzip)> new-file.tgz"
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Comment: Yes its working now :) with bash but I am surprised why this is not working in sh :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried a number of alternatives, and none of them were satisfactory. The best I found was switching over to `Popen`.

```
# this should have the a similar signature to check_call 
def run_in_shell(*args):
    # unfortunately, `args` won't be escaped as it is actually a string argument to bash.
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', ' '.join(args)])
    # This will also work, though I have found users who had problems with it.
    # proc = subprocess.Popen(' '.join(args), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
    stat = proc.wait()
    if stat != 0:
        subprocess.CalledProcessError(returncode=stat, cmd=command)
    return stat

run_in_shell("cat parsing.tgz <(echo -n ''| gzip)> new-file.tgz")
```

As a note: `/bin/sh` has problems with the unescaped parentheses. If you don't want to specify `'/bin/bash'` above, then you will need to escape the paren:

```
args = 'cat parsing.tgz <\\(echo -n ''| gzip\\)> new-file.tgz'
```

Comment: The problem comes with special character ' ' in the args and even the shlex is not recognizing this special character.                                                          viswesn@viswesn:~$ python tar.py
cat parsing.tgz <(echo -n ''| gzip)> new-file.tgz
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Command 'cat parsing.tgz <(echo -n ''| gzip)> new-file.tgz' returned non-zero exit status 2